# VB Entity Framework - Joins to test for presence

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I want to write a VB Entity Framework query to return IDs from table1 that are present in table2 AND NOT present in table3. In TSQL I would write it like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3
    ON t1.ID = t3.ID
WHERE t3.ID IS NULL
```

I've tried several times - no luck getting it right - hence asking here.

```
Dim query = From h In db.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderDBs
Join p In db.TGSPrimerOrders_In_PrimerSetsDB
    On h.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderID Equals p.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderID
Join po In db.TGSPrimerOrders_Out_PrimerSetsDB
    On h.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderID Equals po.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderID
Where po.BarcodeString Is Nothing
Select h Distinct
```

This one returns nothing.

Comment: _I've tried several times_ It would be far better to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I got there myself in the end:

```
Dim query = From h In db.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderDBs
Join po In db.TGSPrimerOrders_Out_PrimerSetsDB
    On h.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderID Equals po.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderID
Group Join pi In db.TGSPrimerOrders_In_PrimerSetsDB
    On h.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderID Equals pi.TGSPrimerOrdersHeaderID
    Into Group
From gp In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
Where gp.BarcodeString Is Nothing
Select h Distinct
```

This one works as expected. Bit long-winded in VB though.